what artifactID shall I use in pom
I'd like to try org.geotools.gce.pgraster but I cant find wich ArtifactId I shall enter in my pom.xml.
How can I find out this?

Assuming that's in the Postgis Raster module then looking in the pom.xml file gives gt-postgis-raster as the artefact id.
